# Relationship between number of public rubbish bins and MSW(municipal Solid Waste) among countries and areas

Tags: waste

Is there any research really about the relationship between the number of public rubbish bins and MSW? Any studies about it?

Do municipalities with less public rubbish bins tend to produce less MSW? Due to the "Culture of Convenience".

Any examples about it?

I need those answers quite bad, any possible suggestions will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Note that even if there were a correlation shown, this wouldn't necessarily demonstrate causality. Both could have a common causal factor, though. For instance, I would expect wealthier societies to both have more trash bins and produce more waste per capita simply because they can afford to buy more trash bins and can afford to buy more stuff that produces waste.

Comment: Less public rubbish bins probably also means more litter.

Comment: Would you expect a relationship? Why?